# Compare 'n' number of lists in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have the following lists:

```
set w {1 2 3 4 5 6 7}
set x {1 2 3 4 5 8 9}
set y {1 2 3 4 0 9 1}
set z {1 2 3 4 5 6 7}
```

I want to compare all the lists - w.r.t corresponding indices -  and find out the common elements and append those common elements to a new list. If I compare the above lists, I see that `1 2 3 4` are common across all the lists and have the same index, so my output should be:

```
{1 2 3 4}
```

If there are no common elements(even at 0'th index) my new list will be empty.

I first start off by creating a list of lists:

```
set l1 [list $w $x $y $z]
```

Then I create a nested loop to compare the lists and extract my common elements, I will be using list 'x' as my reference list:

```
for {set j 0} {$j < [llength $x]} {incr j} {
    for {set i 1} {$i < [llength $l1]} {incr i} {

         set a [lindex [lindex $l1 $i] $j]

         if {$a == [lindex $x $j] && [lindex $l2 $j] == {}} {
                lappend l2 $a
         } else {
           break
         }
    }

}
```

What I'm getting is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively only comparing list `x` against list `x`, and the actual output from your code above (assuming list `l2` is initially empty) is actually:

```
1 2 3 4 5 8 9
```

You might ask:

> Why is it comparing list `x` against list `x`?

Your inner loop starts at index 1 (`set i 1`), which is list `x` in `l1`.

You might further ask:

> Why are the other lists not being compared?

Once you have appended something to `l2`, `lindex $l2 $j` for the next list will never be empty, so the inner loop will break.

---

So, how to do it?

I would probably use something like this:

```
set w {1 2 3 4 5 6 7}
set x {1 2 3 4 5 8 9}
set y {1 2 3 4 0 9 1}
set z {1 2 3 4 5 6 7}

set l1 [list $w $x $y $z]
set l2 [list]

set num [llength $x]

for {set i 0} {$i < $num} {incr i} {
  # This variable will tell us how many matched. 0 indicating none.
  set same 0

  for {set j 0} {$j < [llength $l1]} {incr j} {
    # lindex accepts multiple indices, see the manual
    # using x as reference, if the current list's ith element is the same as x's ith element...
    if {[lindex $l1 $j $i] == [lindex $x $i]} {
      incr same
    }
  }

  # if same reached 4, means 4 matched
  if {$same == 4} {
    lappend l2 [lindex $x $i]
  }
}
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 4
```

---

You could make the inner loop break if the elements do not match, so it won't loop unnecessarily.

Or instead of counting the number of matches, you could check if the inner loop broke with something like:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $num} {incr i} {
  set broke 0

  for {set j 0} {$j < [llength $l1]} {incr j} {
    if {[lindex $l1 $j $i] != [lindex $x $i]} {
      set broke 1
      break
    }
  }

  # if it did not break, then we know all matched
  if {$broke == 0} {
    lappend l2 [lindex $x $i]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I didn't notice that blunder of comparing against the same list, my initial goal was to avoid it and keep the first list in `l1` (or) `w` as my reference and skip it during the comparison. Also, the reason I added `&& [lindex $l2 $j] == {}` was because I was getting `1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5`. I'm still a bit unsure on why my loop isn't terminating when `a` becomes `5`.

Comment: Never mind, I understood. My loop just appends the element even if the element matches the element in the second list. I didn't add code to delete the already appended number if it finds an inequality in the other n-1 lists.

Answer (score 2):

Similar implementation, but using an array to store the unique elements of the slice

```
set lists [list $w $x $y $z]
set common [list]

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $w]} {incr i} {
    array unset elements
    foreach list $lists {
        set elements([lindex $list $i]) dummyvalue
    }
    set unique [array names elements]
    if {[llength $unique] == 1} {
        lappend common $unique
    }
}

puts $common  ;# => 1 2 3 4
```